# Sometimes (randomly) application crash with ntdll.dll as faulting module

Tags: java, windows, dll, crash, j-integra

We have homegrown java application that uses JIntegra.jar. The JAVA application also connects to a application running in .NET. The application works fine most of the time. But sometimes for some unknown reason the application crashesh. When checking the event logs, we find following error

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          02/09/2015 06:56:12
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      XXXXXXXXXXXX
Description:
Faulting application name: Java.exe, version: 5.0.110.3, time stamp: 0x45826b52
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.17736, time stamp: 0x550f42c2
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x00040fa2
Faulting process id: 0x1968
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0e37946abf2c5
Faulting application path: D:\jdk1.5.0_11\bin\Java.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 504040c6-5137-11e5-80dc-005056ac0ab9
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-09-02T05:56:12.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>31747</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>JAVA.exe</Data>
    <Data>5.0.110.3</Data>
    <Data>45826b52</Data>
    <Data>ntdll.dll</Data>
    <Data>6.3.9600.17736</Data>
    <Data>550f42c2</Data>
    <Data>c00000fd</Data>
    <Data>00040fa2</Data>
    <Data>1968</Data>
    <Data>01d0e37946abf2c5</Data>
    <Data>D:\jdk1.5.0_11\bin\JAVA.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll</Data>
    <Data>504040c6-5137-11e5-80dc-005056ac0ab9</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

The triage.dmp files point to following fault. Can someone please shed some light on what the issue can be? As this is a windows log, we dont have much knowledge about it. Please note i can provide more details on request.

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

TRIAGER: Could not open triage file : e:\dump_analysis\program\triage\guids.ini, error 2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for net.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for net.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for jvm.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for jvm.dll
Unable to load image java.dll, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for java.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for java.dll
TRIAGER: Could not open triage file : e:\dump_analysis\program\triage\modclass.ini, error 2
*** The OS name list needs to be updated! Unknown Windows version: 6.3 ***

FAULTING_IP: 
combase!CGIPTable::_RevokeInterfaceFromGlobal+49
76ea9983 8bf8            mov     edi,eax

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 77e50fa2 (ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x00000002)
   ExceptionCode: c00000fd (Stack overflow)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 00000001
   Parameter[1]: 4ae72ffc

PROCESS_NAME:  Java.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc00000fd - A new guard page for the stack cannot be created.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc00000fd - A new guard page for the stack cannot be created.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  00000001

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  4ae72ffc

RECURRING_STACK: From frames 0x4 to 0x1e

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  Followup set based on attribute [Is_OriginalExceptionThread] from Frame:[0] on thread:[1ff0] ; Followup set based on attribute [Is_ChosenCrashFollowupThread] from Frame:[0] on thread:[PSEUDO_THREAD]

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 76e7cc7f to 77e50fa2

FAULTING_THREAD:  ffffffff

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_ACTIONABLE_HEAP_CORRUPTION_heap_failure_invalid_argument_STACK_OVERFLOW_CODE

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  ACTIONABLE_HEAP_CORRUPTION_heap_failure_invalid_argument_CODE

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  ACTIONABLE_HEAP_CORRUPTION_heap_failure_invalid_argument_CODE

STACK_TEXT:  
4ae72ffc 76e7cc7f 76f82c10 aaaaaaaa 00000000 ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x2
4ae73074 76eaa30f 00000000 4ae73098 00000000 combase!FindStdMarshal+0x28e
4ae730a0 76ea9c06 aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa combase!ReleaseMarshalObjRef+0x56
4ae73104 76ea9983 aaaaaaaa 4ae73184 aaaaaaaa combase!CGIPTable::RevokeInterfaceInCurrentApartment+0x222
4ae73140 76e9d717 aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa combase!CGIPTable::_RevokeInterfaceFromGlobal+0x49
4ae73188 76eab7f5 4c4ed0d0 76e724dd aaaaaaaa combase!STAHandlePostedGipRevoke+0x4b
4ae731bc 77577834 aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa combase!ThreadWndProc+0x3fc
4ae731e8 77577a9a 76e724dd aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa user32!_InternalCallWinProc+0x23
4ae73278 7757988e 76e724dd 00000000 aaaaaaaa user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x184
4ae732e4 775798f1 76ee137b 4ae73320 76ee14ee user32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x208
4ae732f0 76ee14ee 4ae73304 777dd190 4ae73520 user32!DispatchMessageW+0x10
4ae73320 76ee1453 4ae73520 4baec960 00000000 combase!CCliModalLoop::PeekRPCAndDDEMessage+0x4f
4ae73340 76f73271 4ae73364 aaaaaaaa 4ae7336c combase!CCliModalLoop::BlockFn+0x17a
4ae733ac 76f716cd 4ae7365c 003170d0 4baec960 combase!ThreadSendReceive+0x1d3
4ae734f4 76eac6ac 003170d0 4ae7365c 4ae73638 combase!CRpcChannelBuffer::SendReceive2+0x1df
4ae735b4 76e73b8f 003170d0 4ae7365c 4ae73638 combase!ClassicSTAThreadSendReceive+0x209
4ae73614 76f714a5 003170d0 4ae7365c 4ae73638 combase!CCtxComChnl::SendReceive+0xf9
4ae7362c 779a5769 002f9684 4ae73688 779a5740 combase!NdrExtpProxySendReceive+0x42
4ae73644 77a26c1b aaaaaaaa 4c3eaf3c 4ae73aa4 rpcrt4!NdrpProxySendReceive+0x29
4ae73a70 76f71a1e 76e69d40 76e6963e 4ae73aa4 rpcrt4!NdrClientCall2+0x22b
4ae73a8c 76e73a83 00000010 aaaaaaaa 4ae73ae8 combase!ObjectStublessClient+0x6b
4ae73a9c 76e7c0f7 002f9684 aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa combase!ObjectStubless+0xf
4ae73ae8 76e772f5 aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa combase!RemoteReleaseRifRef+0x166
4ae73b88 76e762df 4c3eaf38 aaaaaaaa 77e50fa0 combase!CStdMarshal::DisconnectCliIPIDs+0x432
4ae73bc4 76e7659a aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa 00317c28 combase!CStdMarshal::Disconnect+0x183
4ae73bf0 76f700ae aaaaaaaa 4ae73c10 76ea99ab combase!CStdIdentity::CInternalUnk::Release+0x280
4ae73bfc 76ea99ab aaaaaaaa 76ea9995 aaaaaaaa combase!IUnknown_Release_Proxy+0x11
4ae73c10 76ea98de aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa 002f3528 combase!ReleaseCallback+0x16
4ae73c58 76ea97a6 aaaaaaaa 76e64264 aaaaaaaa combase!PerformCallback+0x3e
4ae73cf0 76ea9afb 002f3528 76ea9995 aaaaaaaa combase!CObjectContext::InternalContextCallback+0xd0
4ae73d6c 76ea9983 aaaaaaaa 4ae73dec aaaaaaaa combase!CGIPTable::RevokeInterfaceInCurrentApartment+0x13b
4ae73da8 76e9d717 aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa combase!CGIPTable::_RevokeInterfaceFromGlobal+0x49
4ae73df0 76eab7f5 4c4ece50 76e724dd aaaaaaaa combase!STAHandlePostedGipRevoke+0x4b
4ae73e24 77577834 aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa combase!ThreadWndProc+0x3fc
4ae73e50 77577a9a 76e724dd aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa user32!_InternalCallWinProc+0x23
4ae73ee0 7757988e 76e724dd 00000000 aaaaaaaa user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x184
4ae73f4c 775798f1 76ee137b 4ae73f88 76ee14ee user32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x208
4ae73f58 76ee14ee 4ae73f6c 777dd190 4ae74188 user32!DispatchMessageW+0x10
4ae73f88 76ee1453 4ae74188 4baedc78 00000000 combase!CCliModalLoop::PeekRPCAndDDEMessage+0x4f
4ae73fa8 76f73271 4ae73fcc aaaaaaaa 4ae73fd4 combase!CCliModalLoop::BlockFn+0x17a
4ae74014 76f716cd 4ae742c4 003170d0 4baedc78 combase!ThreadSendReceive+0x1d3
4ae7415c 76eac6ac 003170d0 4ae742c4 4ae742a0 combase!CRpcChannelBuffer::SendReceive2+0x1df
4ae7421c 76e73b8f 003170d0 4ae742c4 4ae742a0 combase!ClassicSTAThreadSendReceive+0x209
4ae7427c 76f714a5 003170d0 4ae742c4 4ae742a0 combase!CCtxComChnl::SendReceive+0xf9
4ae74294 779a5769 002f9684 4ae742f0 779a5740 combase!NdrExtpProxySendReceive+0x42
4ae742ac 77a26c1b aaaaaaaa 4c3ed83c 4ae7470c rpcrt4!NdrpProxySendReceive+0x29
4ae746d8 76f71a1e 76e69d40 76e6963e 4ae7470c rpcrt4!NdrClientCall2+0x22b
4ae746f4 76e73a83 00000010 aaaaaaaa 4ae74750 combase!ObjectStublessClient+0x6b
4ae74704 76e7c0f7 002f9684 aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa combase!ObjectStubless+0xf
4ae74750 76e772f5 aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa combase!RemoteReleaseRifRef+0x166
4ae747f0 76e762df 4c3ed838 aaaaaaaa 77e50fa0 combase!CStdMarshal::DisconnectCliIPIDs+0x432
4ae7482c 76e7659a aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa 00317c28 combase!CStdMarshal::Disconnect+0x183
4ae74858 76f700ae aaaaaaaa 4ae74878 76ea99ab combase!CStdIdentity::CInternalUnk::Release+0x280
4ae74864 76ea99ab aaaaaaaa 76ea9995 aaaaaaaa combase!IUnknown_Release_Proxy+0x11
4ae74878 76ea98de aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa 002f3528 combase!ReleaseCallback+0x16
4ae748c0 76ea97a6 aaaaaaaa 76e64264 aaaaaaaa combase!PerformCallback+0x3e
4ae74958 76ea9afb 002f3528 76ea9995 aaaaaaaa combase!CObjectContext::InternalContextCallback+0xd0
4ae749d4 76ea9983 aaaaaaaa 4ae74a54 aaaaaaaa combase!CGIPTable::RevokeInterfaceInCurrentApartment+0x13b
4ae74a10 76e9d717 aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa combase!CGIPTable::_RevokeInterfaceFromGlobal+0x49
4ae74a58 76eab7f5 4c4ecfe0 76e724dd aaaaaaaa combase!STAHandlePostedGipRevoke+0x4b
4ae74a8c 77577834 aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa combase!ThreadWndProc+0x3fc
4ae74ab8 77577a9a 76e724dd aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa user32!_InternalCallWinProc+0x23
4ae74b48 7757988e 76e724dd 00000000 aaaaaaaa user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x184
4ae74bb4 775798f1 76ee137b 4ae74bf0 76ee14ee user32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x208
4ae74bc0 76ee14ee 4ae74bd4 777dd190 4ae74df0 user32!DispatchMessageW+0x10
4ae74bf0 76ee1453 4ae74df0 4c58cef8 00000000 combase!CCliModalLoop::PeekRPCAndDDEMessage+0x4f
4ae74c10 76f73271 4ae74c34 aaaaaaaa 4ae74c3c combase!CCliModalLoop::BlockFn+0x17a
4ae74c7c 76f716cd 4ae74f2c 003170d0 4c58cef8 combase!ThreadSendReceive+0x1d3
4ae74dc4 76eac6ac 003170d0 4ae74f2c 4ae74f08 combase!CRpcChannelBuffer::SendReceive2+0x1df
4ae74e84 76e73b8f 003170d0 4ae74f2c 4ae74f08 combase!ClassicSTAThreadSendReceive+0x209
4ae74ee4 76f714a5 003170d0 4ae74f2c 4ae74f08 combase!CCtxComChnl::SendReceive+0xf9
4ae74efc 779a5769 002f9684 4ae74f58 779a5740 combase!NdrExtpProxySendReceive+0x42
4ae74f14 77a26c1b aaaaaaaa 4c3ed93c 4ae75374 rpcrt4!NdrpProxySendReceive+0x29
4ae75340 76f71a1e 76e69d40 76e6963e 4ae75374 rpcrt4!NdrClientCall2+0x22b
4ae7535c 76e73a83 00000010 aaaaaaaa 4ae753b8 combase!ObjectStublessClient+0x6b
4ae7536c 76e7c0f7 002f9684 aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa combase!ObjectStubless+0xf
4ae753b8 76e772f5 aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa combase!RemoteReleaseRifRef+0x166
4ae75458 76e762df 4c3ed938 aaaaaaaa 77e50fa0 combase!CStdMarshal::DisconnectCliIPIDs+0x432
4ae75494 76e7659a aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa 00317c28 combase!CStdMarshal::Disconnect+0x183
4ae754c0 76f700ae aaaaaaaa 4ae754e0 76ea99ab combase!CStdIdentity::CInternalUnk::Release+0x280
4ae754cc 76ea99ab aaaaaaaa 76ea9995 aaaaaaaa combase!IUnknown_Release_Proxy+0x11
4ae754e0 76ea98de aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa 002f3528 combase!ReleaseCallback+0x16
4ae75528 76ea97a6 aaaaaaaa 76e64264 aaaaaaaa combase!PerformCallback+0x3e
4ae755c0 76ea9afb 002f3528 76ea9995 aaaaaaaa combase!CObjectContext::InternalContextCallback+0xd0
4ae7563c 76ea9983 aaaaaaaa 4ae756bc 4c4ecda8 combase!CGIPTable::RevokeInterfaceInCurrentApartment+0x13b
4ae75678 76e9d717 aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa combase!CGIPTable::_RevokeInterfaceFromGlobal+0x49
4ae756c0 76eab7f5 4c4ecd88 76e724dd aaaaaaaa combase!STAHandlePostedGipRevoke+0x4b
4ae756f4 77577834 aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa combase!ThreadWndProc+0x3fc
4ae75720 77577a9a 76e724dd aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa user32!_InternalCallWinProc+0x23
4ae757b0 7757988e 76e724dd 00000000 aaaaaaaa user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x184
4ae7581c 775798f1 76ee137b 4ae75858 76ee14ee user32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x208
4ae75828 76ee14ee 4ae7583c 777dd190 4ae75a58 user32!DispatchMessageW+0x10
4ae75858 76ee1453 4ae75a58 4c58c7a0 00000000 combase!CCliModalLoop::PeekRPCAndDDEMessage+0x4f
4ae75878 76f73271 4ae7589c aaaaaaaa 4ae758a4 combase!CCliModalLoop::BlockFn+0x17a
4ae758e4 76f716cd 4ae75b94 003170d0 4c58c7a0 combase!ThreadSendReceive+0x1d3
4ae75a2c 76eac6ac 003170d0 4ae75b94 4ae75b70 combase!CRpcChannelBuffer::SendReceive2+0x1df
4ae75aec 76e73b8f 003170d0 4ae75b94 4ae75b70 combase!ClassicSTAThreadSendReceive+0x209
4ae75b4c 76f714a5 003170d0 4ae75b94 4ae75b70 combase!CCtxComChnl::SendReceive+0xf9
4ae75b64 779a5769 002f9684 4ae75bc0 779a5740 combase!NdrExtpProxySendReceive+0x42
4ae75b7c 77a26c1b aaaaaaaa 4c3ece3c 4ae75fdc rpcrt4!NdrpProxySendReceive+0x29
4ae75fa8 76f71a1e 76e69d40 76e6963e 4ae75fdc rpcrt4!NdrClientCall2+0x22b
4ae75fc4 76e73a83 00000010 aaaaaaaa 4ae76020 combase!ObjectStublessClient+0x6b
4ae75fd4 76e7c0f7 002f9684 aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa combase!ObjectStubless+0xf
4ae76020 76e772f5 aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa combase!RemoteReleaseRifRef+0x166
4ae760c0 76e762df 4c3ece38 aaaaaaaa 77e50fa0 combase!CStdMarshal::DisconnectCliIPIDs+0x432
4ae760fc 76e7659a aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa 00317c28 combase!CStdMarshal::Disconnect+0x183
4ae76128 76f700ae aaaaaaaa 4ae76148 76ea99ab combase!CStdIdentity::CInternalUnk::Release+0x280
4ae76134 76ea99ab aaaaaaaa 76ea9995 aaaaaaaa combase!IUnknown_Release_Proxy+0x11
4ae76148 76ea98de aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa 002f3528 combase!ReleaseCallback+0x16
4ae76190 76ea97a6 aaaaaaaa 76e64264 aaaaaaaa combase!PerformCallback+0x3e
4ae76228 76ea9afb 002f3528 76ea9995 aaaaaaaa combase!CObjectContext::InternalContextCallback+0xd0
4ae762a4 76ea9983 aaaaaaaa 4ae76324 aaaaaaaa combase!CGIPTable::RevokeInterfaceInCurrentApartment+0x13b
4ae762e0 76e9d717 aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa combase!CGIPTable::_RevokeInterfaceFromGlobal+0x49
4ae76328 76eab7f5 4c4ed0a8 76e724dd aaaaaaaa combase!STAHandlePostedGipRevoke+0x4b
4ae7635c 77577834 aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa combase!ThreadWndProc+0x3fc
4ae76388 77577a9a 76e724dd aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa user32!_InternalCallWinProc+0x23
4ae76418 7757988e 76e724dd 00000000 aaaaaaaa user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x184
4ae76484 775798f1 76ee137b 4ae764c0 76ee14ee user32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x208
4ae76490 76ee14ee 4ae764a4 777dd190 4ae766c0 user32!DispatchMessageW+0x10
4ae764c0 76ee1453 4ae766c0 4c58c338 00000000 combase!CCliModalLoop::PeekRPCAndDDEMessage+0x4f
4ae764e0 76f73271 4ae76504 aaaaaaaa 4ae7650c combase!CCliModalLoop::BlockFn+0x17a
4ae7654c 76f716cd 4ae767fc 003170d0 4c58c338 combase!ThreadSendReceive+0x1d3
4ae76694 76eac6ac 003170d0 4ae767fc 4ae767d8 combase!CRpcChannelBuffer::SendReceive2+0x1df
4ae76754 76e73b8f 003170d0 4ae767fc 4ae767d8 combase!ClassicSTAThreadSendReceive+0x209
4ae767b4 76f714a5 003170d0 4ae767fc 4ae767d8 combase!CCtxComChnl::SendReceive+0xf9
4ae767cc 779a5769 002f9684 4ae76828 779a5740 combase!NdrExtpProxySendReceive+0x42
4ae767e4 77a26c1b aaaaaaaa 4c3ec33c 4ae76c44 rpcrt4!NdrpProxySendReceive+0x29
4ae76c10 76f71a1e 76e69d40 76e6963e 4ae76c44 rpcrt4!NdrClientCall2+0x22b
4ae76c2c 76e73a83 00000010 aaaaaaaa 4ae76c88 combase!ObjectStublessClient+0x6b
4ae76c3c 76e7c0f7 002f9684 aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa combase!ObjectStubless+0xf
4ae76c88 76e772f5 aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa combase!RemoteReleaseRifRef+0x166
4ae76d28 76e762df 4c3ec338 aaaaaaaa 77e50fa0 combase!CStdMarshal::DisconnectCliIPIDs+0x432
4ae76d64 76e7659a aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa 00317c28 combase!CStdMarshal::Disconnect+0x183
4ae76d90 76f700ae aaaaaaaa 4ae76db0 76ea99ab combase!CStdIdentity::CInternalUnk::Release+0x280
4ae76d9c 76ea99ab aaaaaaaa 76ea9995 aaaaaaaa combase!IUnknown_Release_Proxy+0x11
4ae76db0 76ea98de aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa 002f3528 combase!ReleaseCallback+0x16
4ae76df8 76ea97a6 aaaaaaaa 76e64264 aaaaaaaa combase!PerformCallback+0x3e
4ae76e90 76ea9afb 002f3528 76ea9995 aaaaaaaa combase!CObjectContext::InternalContextCallback+0xd0
4ae76f0c 76ea9983 aaaaaaaa 4ae76f8c 4c4ec998 combase!CGIPTable::RevokeInterfaceInCurrentApartment+0x13b
4ae76f48 76e9d717 aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa combase!CGIPTable::_RevokeInterfaceFromGlobal+0x49
4ae76f90 76eab7f5 4c4ec978 76e724dd aaaaaaaa combase!STAHandlePostedGipRevoke+0x4b
4ae76fc4 77577834 aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa combase!ThreadWndProc+0x3fc
4ae76ff0 77577a9a 76e724dd aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa user32!_InternalCallWinProc+0x23
4ae77080 7757988e 76e724dd 00000000 aaaaaaaa user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x184
4ae770ec 775798f1 76ee137b 4ae77128 76ee14ee user32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x208
4ae770f8 76ee14ee 4ae7710c 777dd190 4ae77328 user32!DispatchMessageW+0x10
4ae77128 76ee1453 4ae77328 4c58c628 00000000 combase!CCliModalLoop::PeekRPCAndDDEMessage+0x4f

STACK_COMMAND:  .ecxr ; ~~[1ff0] ; .frame 0 ; ddS 4ae71000 4aeb0000 ; ~11s; .ecxr ; kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
jvm+b7246
6d6f7246 ??              ???

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  22

SYMBOL_NAME:  jvm+b7246

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: jvm

IMAGE_NAME:  jvm.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  458285b6

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  ACTIONABLE_HEAP_CORRUPTION_heap_failure_invalid_argument_CODE_c00000fd_jvm.dll!Unknown

BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_ACTIONABLE_HEAP_CORRUPTION_heap_failure_invalid_argument_STACK_OVERFLOW_CODE_jvm+b7246
```

Comment: Forgot to mention.. The machine on which the application is running also has "Trend Micro" anti virus, OS= Windows server 2012 R2

Comment: issue face by me is something similar to the one faced by Alex in the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21445990/java-randomly-crashing-possible-culprite-ntdll-dll

Comment: can this also be related to http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/javatm-platform-binary-has-stopped-working/94d4ffc0-5ec6-4835-a7b5-a2581b782605 ?

Comment: have you ever found a solution?

Comment: @gismo : unfortunately we never found a solution. But observed a weird behavior, we replaced the system having the issue with a completely new one (formatted and reinstalled windows and other drivers) and have not encountered the issue ever since.